# Excel VBA filter value in column and copy info into another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, filter, copy-paste

(Ignore the fact that the code has been commented out)

I have a workbook ("BOM Template") with one sheet ("Ozone Generator skid") in it. On that sheet, I have a table starting at row 8. There are check boxes for each table row. When those checkboxes are selected and then a button is clicked, I want another workbook to open. That workbook ("Instrument Data Sheet") is formatted a certain way with a template sheet for the format inside it called "Temp_Datasheet." For every unique "data sheet name" entered in column C of the original workbook, a sheet formatted exactly like Temp_Datasheet must be created in the new workbook. All "tag numbers" and their "process locations" with the same "data sheet name" must appear on the same sheet in the new workbook (tag number 1 will go (2,3) in Temp_Datasheet then that tag number's process location will appear in (2,4). The next tag number will appear in (2,5), etc.)

I can get the template Temp_Datasheet to open but that's all. The code is not creating new sheets for each unique datasheet and it isn't populating the sheet with the corresponding information.
Please help!

```
'Private Sub CommandButt_Click()              ' instrument data sheet
'
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'
'Dim CounterQTY, rowcounter, colcounter, lastcell, actcell, nextcell, cnt As Integer
'Dim MySheetName, TagNr As String
'Dim WS As Worksheet
'Dim CHK As Boolean
'Dim wbTarget As Workbook 'workbook where the data is to be pasted
'Dim wbThis As Workbook 'workbook from where the data is to copied
'Dim strName As String   'name of the source sheet/ target workbook
''On Error Resume Next
'
'
''***************************************************************************************
''search lastRow
''***************************************************************************************
'
'Dim LastCellA As Range
'Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long
'
'Set searchWS = Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid")
'    With searchWS
'        Set LastCellB = .Cells(.rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
'        LastCellRowNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(LastCellB.Row)
'    End With
'
'
'
''***************************************************************************************
''create new sheet
''***************************************************************************************
'
''clear any thing on clipboard to maximize available memory
'Application.CutCopyMode = False
'
''set to the current active workbook (the source book)
'Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook
'
''get the active sheetname of the book
'strName = ThisWorkbook.Path
'
''open a workbook that has same name as the sheet name (the workbook and the sheet inside it have the same name?) JK: now I think this is saying the file that will have all the valve data sheets in it (wbTarget) will have the name of the file that is being opened from the Vault link below (Ex: "Water Instrument Sheet") and inside that file "Water Instrument Sheet" in the Vault, the sheet name is called "Temp_Datasheet" and is invisible, waiting to become visible. I can just download a copy of a valve and instrument data sheet, move it to my Vault folder, rename the file however I want, and then paste the link here. And since "Temp_Datasheet" is already inside the data sheet file, I need not worry about anything except filling in the accurate ranges for the info below!
'
'Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Degremont Vault\ONA\Templates\Templates Activated by BOM\Instrument Data Sheet.xlsx")
'
''activate the source book
'wbThis.Activate
'
'For i = 8 To LastCellRowNumber
'
'    lastcell = Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid").Cells(i - 1, 3).Value
'    actcell = Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid").Cells(i, 3).Value
'
'        If actcell <> lastcell And Not (IsEmpty(actcell)) And Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid").OLEObjects("CHK" & i).Object.Value = True Then
'
'        rowcounter = 2                                                          ' reset tag field
'        colcounter = 3
'        CounterQTY = 1
'
'        MySheetName = Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid").Cells(i, 3).Text
'
'        wbTarget.Activate
'            For Each WS In wbTarget.Worksheets
'                Worksheets("Temp_Datasheet").Visible = True
'                If InStr(WS.Name, MySheetName) = 1 Then
'                    CHK = True
'                    cnt = cnt + 1
'                End If
'            Next
'
'            If CHK Then
'                Sheets("Temp_Datasheet").Select                                       ' create new sheet if sheet already exist
'                Sheets("Temp_Datasheet").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
'                ActiveSheet.Name = MySheetName & "_" & cnt
'                ActiveSheet.Unprotect
'            Else
'                Sheets("Temp_Datasheet").Select                                        ' create new sheet
'                Sheets("Temp_Datasheet").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
'                ActiveSheet.Name = MySheetName
'                ActiveSheet.Unprotect
'            End If
'        Worksheets("Temp_Datasheet").Visible = False
'
'
''***************************************************************************************
''copy and paste specific cells to new sheet
''***************************************************************************************
'        ActiveSheet.Range("C11").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid").Cells(i, 8).Value          ' MM#
'        ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid").Cells(i, 4).Value           ' Tag #
'        ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid").Cells(i, 32).Value           ' Material Description
'        ActiveSheet.Range("C12").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid").Cells(i, 20).Value          ' Manufacturer
'        ActiveSheet.Range("C13").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid ").Cells(i, 19).Value          ' Model #
'        ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid ").Cells(i, 4).Value           ' Process Location
'        ActiveSheet.Range("C14").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid ").Cells(i, 17).Value          ' Material/Body Material
'        ActiveSheet.Range("C15").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid ").Cells(i, 18).Value         ' Connection
'        ActiveSheet.Range("C16").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid ").Cells(i, 27).Value         ' Power
'        ActiveSheet.Range("C17").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid ").Cells(i, 26).Value         ' Instrument Range
'        ActiveSheet.Range("C18").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid ").Cells(i, 30).Value         ' Design Range
'        ActiveSheet.Range("F18").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid ").Cells(i, 28).Value         ' Alarm
'        ActiveSheet.Range("H18").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid ").Cells(i, 29).Value         ' Interlock
'        ActiveSheet.Range("C19").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid ").Cells(i, 31).Value         ' Options on the Data Sheet corresponds to Oxygen Cleaned from the BOM
'        ActiveSheet.Range("C25").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid ").Cells(i, 34).Value         ' Notes
'        ActiveSheet.Range("C10").Value = 1
'
''***************************************************************************************
''copy and paste information from header to new sheet
''***************************************************************************************
'        ActiveSheet.Range("A28").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid ").Range("AB5").Value   ' Issued
'        ActiveSheet.Range("A30").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid ").Range("AD5").Value   ' checked
'        ActiveSheet.Range("A32").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid ").Range("AF5").Value   ' approved
'        ActiveSheet.Range("C27").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid ").Range("N2").Value   ' project name
'        ActiveSheet.Range("C29").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid ").Range("N3").Value   ' project #
'        ActiveSheet.Range("H31").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid ").Cells(i, 35).Value  ' Rev
'        ActiveSheet.Range("F30").Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid ").Cells(i, 3).Value   ' Sheet #
'
'        End If
'
''***************************************************************************************
''copy and paste only Tag # to same specsheet
''***************************************************************************************
'    wbThis.Activate
'
'    If actcell = lastcell And Not (IsEmpty(actcell)) And Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid").OLEObjects("CHK" & i).Object.Value = True Then
'        colcounter = colcounter + 2
'            If colcounter > 8 Then
'                colcounter = 3
'                rowcounter = rowcounter + 1
'            End If
'        wbTarget.Worksheets(MySheetName).Cells(rowcounter, colcounter).Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid").Cells(i, 4).Value ' Tag #
'        wbTarget.Worksheets(MySheetName).Cells(rowcounter, colcounter + 1).Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid").Cells(i, 8).Value ' Process Location
'        CounterQTY = CounterQTY + 1
'        wbTarget.Worksheets(MySheetName).Range("C10").Value = CounterQTY
'
'    End If
'
'Next i
'
'
'wbThis.Activate
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'
''Clear memory
'Set wbTarget = Nothing
'Set wbThis = Nothing
'
'
'End Sub
```

Comment: For starters, remove `On Error Resume Next`, which silently hides errors when you really should handle them. What errors occur? Also, you have `wbThis` but then use `ThisWorkbook` - are they one and the same?

Comment: On Error Resume Next is commented out when I use the code ('' not just '). I think the problem occurs prior to Worksheets("Temp_Datasheet").Visible = False but it tells me  "Subscript out of range" for wbTarget.Worksheets(MySheetName).Cells(rowcounter, colcounter).Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid").Cells(i, 4).Value ' Tag #

Comment: Everything has been named correctly I believe so I don't see how the error "Subscript out of range applies." And I believe there is an error previous to that anyway since at Worksheets("Temp_Datasheet").Visible = False another worksheet should be created but when I run the code, that isn't the case (no other sheet is created, only Temp_Datasheet is visible)

Answer (score 0):

You have two main problems that can be seen from this line:

```
wbTarget.Worksheets(MySheetName).Cells(rowcounter, colcounter).Value = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid").Cells(i, 4).Value ' Tag #
```

1) Your new worksheet at that is not being recognized. This could be a scope issue, but a simple way to fix it is to actually add that new sheet by adding these two lines of code before that line:

```
MySheetName = wbThis.Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid").Cells(i, 3).Text
wbTarget.Worksheets.Add(After:=wbTarget.Worksheets(wbTarget.Worksheets.Count)).Name = MySheetName
```

2) Even when you do that, your scoping is off, as in that same line, `rowcounter` is actually undefined. To fix this, you can move the `rowcounter`, `colcounter`, and `CounterQTY` declarations before the if statement as shown below:

```
For i = 8 To LastCellRowNumber

    lastcell = Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid").Cells(i - 1, 3).Value
    actcell = Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid").Cells(i, 3).Value

        rowcounter = 2                                                          ' reset tag field
        colcounter = 3
        CounterQTY = 1

        If actcell <> lastcell And Not (IsEmpty(actcell)) And Worksheets("Ozone Generator Skid").OLEObjects("CHK" & i).Object.Value
= True Then
```

After that, it's just a matter of updating your code to match the template and handle edge cases and error checks, and you should be populating!